# C# Entity Framework Relationship Beginner Question

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am new to the Entity Framework and trying to work my way into it. I am working with the following:

Database type: SQLite

2 tables, generated with

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts 
(
    AccountId STRING, 
    DisplayName STRING, 
    PRIMARY KEY (AccountId)
)

CREATE TABLE Reviews 
(
    Author STRING, 
    CreatedOn STRING, 
    Id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)
```

Entities in C#:

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(AccountId))]
class AccountEntry 
{
    public string? AccountId { get; set; }
    public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id))]
class ReviewEntry
{
    public string? Author { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AccountEntry? AuthorAccount { get; set; }
}
```

My aim is to have the `AuthorAccount` field filled in with an `AccountEntry` object derived from the lookup that uses the Id from the field `Author` for a lookup in the Accounts table.

To that end I have overloaded `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ReviewEntry>()
        .HasOne(e => e.AuthorAccount)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<ReviewEntry>(e => e.Author);
}
```

Accessing the `DbSet<ReviewEntry>` from my `DbContext`-derived class doesn't raise an exception, but the `AuthorAccount` property in the retrieved `ReviewEntry` data sets is always `null` and I can't figure out why (`ReviewEntry.Account` does contain a valid account Id that is available in the `Accounts` table).

Comment: EF Core do not load navigation property automatically, you have to use `DbSet<ReviewEntry>().Include(x => x.AuthorAccount)`

Comment: `.Include(x => AuthorAccount).ToList()` did behave weird in that it set `AuthorAccount` _and_ `Author` to `null` (and `Include` was indeed taken from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`). But explicit loading via `context.Entry(x).Reference("AuthorAccount").Load()` works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @Svytoslav Danyliv for pointing me into the right direction! In case anyone else has similar issues there is a Microsoft page that neatly lists the various methods for Lazy and Eager loading of referenced entities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data